# Soft keyboard input not working properly in Android WebView while scrolling

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView in my Android app that displays an HTML form with an input field. When I tap the input field, the soft keyboard shows up and I can type normally. However, as soon as I scroll down the WebView even a little bit, the cursor disappears and I cannot type anything anymore.

I have tried various solutions, such as calling `setFocusable(true)` and `requestFocus()` on the WebView and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` , etc.

Also I tried creating a custom WebView that extends the default WebView class and overrides the onTouchEvent() method to handle vertical scrolling, but that didn't seem to solve the problem.

Here's my current code:

```
public class TouchyWebView extends WebView {

    private float lastX;
    private float lastY;
    private boolean dragging;

    public TouchyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TouchyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                lastX = event.getX();
                lastY = event.getY();
                dragging = false;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float deltaX = Math.abs(event.getX() - lastX);
                float deltaY = Math.abs(event.getY() - lastY);

                if (!dragging && deltaY > deltaX) {
                    // Vertical scroll, disable WebView touch
                    requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                } else {
                    dragging = true;
                }

                lastX = event.getX();
                lastY = event.getY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this issue and allow users to type in the input field even after scrolling the WebView?